# Excel VBA Runtime error 1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Upon clicking run, I kept getting the runtime error 1004 and the codes in brackets below gets highlighted. Any one can help me with this

```
Private Sub Add_Click()

  Sheet4.Activate 
  (Range("A1").End(x1Down).Offset(1, 0).Select)

  ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = TextBox2.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = TextBox3.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = ComboBox1.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ComboBox2.Value
  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = TextBox4.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: You have a misprint - `x1Down` instead of `xlDown`. `x1Down` is treated as a variable name, which not exists. Use Intellisense if you are not careful.

Answer (score -1):

*To get rid from the error replace row 2, 3 & 4 
 with this:*

```
Worksheets("Sheet4").Activate 
Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
```

**Note,** *`End(x1Down)` should written like `End(xlDown)`, as also been suggested by @AKINA in comments above.*

Comment: Unnecessarily  down voted since working properly !!